# How to install Revolution R Enterprise, an rpm, when alien fails?

Tags: software-installation, python, rpm

[Revolution R Enterprise](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/products/revolution-enterprise.php) is available as a red-hat rpm file. Normally I would use `alien` to install an rpm file as explained in [another more generic question about installing rpms](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms) , but the instructions for installing this package have an `install.py` file that I am supposed to execute.

When I [`./install.py`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/548395/), I get the following instructions:

> rpm: please use alien to install rpm
>   packages on Debian, if you are really
>   sure use --force-debian switch. See
>   README.Debian for more details.

There is no `README.Debian` file in the directory, and although I am not proficient in python, I can tell that there are at least four different directories with *rpm files in them.

Has anyone had success with this? If possible, I'd prefer to install the Enterprise version instead of community version in the Ubuntu repository so that I can test it out.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of install.py [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) then add the link to your answer?

Comment: here is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/548395/ does that violate any copyright? I will presume not since it is just an install script.

Comment: The use of RPMs looks pretty hard coded and this installer script seems to call several other installer scripts so there doesn't seem to be an easy way to edit the installer script to make it work. Maybe someone else will know what to do if you wait a while. You could also try asking on [their forums](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forumdisplay.php?20-Installation). From [here](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/why-revolution-r/which-r-is-right-for-me.php) it looks like their enterprise version doesn't work on Ubuntu but the community version does. You could also try R from the repos.

Comment: @dv3500ea thanks for looking in to that. i have long had `r-core` installed,  but I was hoping to get the Enterprise version working. I have installed the community version using `apt-get install revolution-r`, but hope to get the enterprise version going too.

Comment: Support for a non-Ubuntu commercial software should be asked there: e.g. http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forum.php

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but how do you start the community version of revolution r after installing it? R just brings up the regular version I had earlier, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(non) Answer:**

No one has figured out [how to install the .rpm using alien or otherwise](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forums/showthread.php?726-RevolutionR-Enterprise-for-Ubuntu); even using Wine to host the Windows version [does not work](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forums/showthread.php?83-REvolution-R-in-wine).

**Good news / options:**

1. the community edition works is available in the [Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=revolution-r&searchon=names)
2. Revolution R Enterprise is officially supported (only) on RedHat; but RevolutionR (the company) has also tested and found no no issues, on [CentOS](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forums/showthread.php?1054-Install-in-ArchLinux), which is freely available and 100% compatible with Redhat. Furthermore, Revolution R Enterprise will install on any distro with rpm; there is evidence of success with [Fedora](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forums/showthread.php?1045-Installing-revolution-enterprise-4-on-fedora).

Comment: I learned as much myself, but thank you for providing the well-referenced answer. Hopefully someone will figure this one out, but for now I will see how CentOS works in a VM.

Comment: Could you fill in the details about how the community edition works? (That link is dead.) I installed it, but nothing like `Revo64` was installed, despite what the [company's linux install doc](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-enterprise-7-linux-installation-instructions) says.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander I have updated the link, I have moved on from trying to accomplish install of the rpm on Ubuntu.