# How to get RPM install in my Ubuntu Linux system?

Tags: rpm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and manage RPMs in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms-in-ubuntu)

I can't open git-0.99.1.rpm.
So, I need the rpm command to install git-0.99.1.rpm.
Is there any supply for the rpm command in Ubuntu Linux?
How can I install the git-0.99.1.rpm package?

Comment: You should probably change this question to "How do I install git?" instead.

Answer (score 24):

Here is how you can install RPM packages on Ubuntu:

Convert RPM package to *.deb using alien and install it afterwards, i.e.

- Install alien (and deps), its available in Debian, Ubuntu repository:

`sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential`

- Convert rpm package using command

`sudo alien -k --scripts some-rpm-package.rpm`

- Install it using this command

`sudo dpkg -i some-rpm-package.deb`

Comment: Convert rpm , I use “sudo alien -k some-rpm-package.rpm”
 but , the computer said that "alien command not found"!

Comment: @Angela: Did you install alien first? If yes then please make sure alien binary is in your path or use full path to alien in sudo alien command.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use rpms on Ubuntu -- you use apt. Just type

sudo apt-get install git

and you'll be all set!

Comment: I am sorry that my computer said:

Comment: Packate git is not available. And I don't know why?? Maybe it's path, maybe it's ownship. Anyway, I didn't find way out.

Answer (score 0):

Go here, https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa, and `Read about installing`.  You just have to add the PPA to your system and you can install with apt.  If you really can't figure it out, you can download the .deb file for your architecture from the bottom of that same page and install with `sudo dpkg -i [filename]`  anubhava did mention that you can use alien to convert .rpm files to .deb, but you don't want to do this--at least not for git when there are .debs available and it's in a repo.  alien is (for me) a last resort (after trying to compile from source).