# Alien for RPM - taking forever

Tags: oracle, alien

I'm trying to unpack a pretty small rpm (5.5MB) according the instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30770/how-to-get-rpm-install-in-my-ubuntu-linux-system) and elsewhere. It's an Oracle InstantClient, if that makes a difference, and I'm trying to install it from windows 10's linux subsystem

I've successfully installed alien, but the actual `sudo alien` command isn't terminating. I've tried it both plain (`sudo alien filename.rpm`) and with some suggested arguments (`sudo alien -k --scripts filename.rpm`), waited 15 minutes both times, and it still hangs.

Comment: `rpm` file on Ubuntu?

Comment: Without any sort of error message it is going to be difficult to solve the problem. Your situation is fairly complex, however, as you are using bash on windows, which may not support the .Oracle application, and Oracle may not support your version of Ubuntu (check the Oracle web site, they typically are very detailed about supported OS and install instructions), and alien can not always convert packages. You are better off finding a deb or installing from source code.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - yes alien is a potential mechanism to convert .rpm to .deb (and other packages), with mixed results, and sometimes bad results as rpm and deb have different mechanisms of lib names, dependencies (names of libs), differences in compile options, and pre/post install scripts, or even init scripts, depending on versions of RHEL (oracle typically supports RHEL over other .rpm systems, but not always) / Ubuntu the rpm was targeted for .

Comment: You can also try extracting the rpm and manually installing - https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html