# Wanted to install RPM based software or application?

Tags: rpm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms)

As I see more application/softwares are distributed in rpm format, I would like to know if 
I should choice from the below two.

1. [`YUM`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/yum)
2. [`Alien`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto)

Are there any better("Stable/Advanced") tool available for installation/remove/update of rpm format application/softwares under ubuntu..

Comment: I don't know where you're looking at but i see more debs than rpms, to convert rpms to debs you have to use `alien` or Alien-gui, if you want a gui.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the deb for that program. There's no reason to use rpm on ubuntu bcz debs are more popular than rpm. And it's unlikely that a linux program provides rpm wihout providing a deb, unless that program is *specifically* for rpm distros like Fedora ^^.

Comment: There's software that provides only debs and tar files, does that mean said software is specifically only for debian-based distros?.

Comment: [F-Secure Linux Security](http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/business_global/support/downloads/-/carousel/view/83) provides only RPM.