# I have a rpm file how do I convert to deb file for running on ubuntu?

Tags: deb, rpm, format-conversion, alien

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms)

I have a *.rpm file that I like to install on Ubuntu. Is it possible to convert a *.rpm to *.deb package?