# How can I batch convert .rpms to .debs in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, deb, rpm, alien

I want to install the daily current build of LibreOffice in Ubuntu but they only make it available in `.rpms`.

I know I'm supposed to use Alien to convet `.rpms` to `.debs` but I can't find a command to batch convert all of them in the RPMS folder in my Ubuntu 12.04. (There's dozens)

I know there's a command to batch install `.debs`, but I'm looking for a similar one to convert `.rpms`.

Does anybody know a command that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Note it is not that hard to compile LibreOffice yourself: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gIqOOajdYQ&amp;hd=1 and it then actually uses your system and is not build against some ancient baseline from years ago (e.g. not having a recent glib, and thus no unity integration). Also note that there is a binary repo with > 250 Ubuntu Libreoffice builds available for regression hunting: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/HowToBibisect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms)

Answer (score 2):

**To convert a .rpm file to .deb format**,

open the Terminal from CTRL +ALT +T

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo apt-get update
```

After that, go to the directory where you have saved the .rpm file. To head over to the desired directory, type the command “cd directory name”. Once you are directed to the appropriate directory, enter the command:

Copy the following code to convert .rpm to .deb format.

```
sudo alien -k filename.rpm
```

Open the .deb file with ubuntu software centre.

**To Convert a .deb file to .rpm**

Type the following into the terminal.

```
sudo alien -r FILE_NAME.deb
NEW_FILE_NAME.noarch.rpm generated
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to install the daily current build of LibreOffice in Ubuntu but they only make it available in .rpms.

That is not true. The [daily dev buils](http://dev-builds.libreoffice.org/daily/libreoffice-5-2/Linux-rpm_deb-x86@71-TDF/2016-09-17_01.33.59/) contain DEBs. And they had them for a long time since [this was answered and closed in 2012](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/9157/deb-repository-for-daily-builds/).