# how to copy updates from 1 linux box to another using cli remote serial and usb drive

Tags: installation, usb, package-management, serial-port

I have 2 old pc's that I'm going to remote into using serial port/tcp. The first one is a 32-bit machine that I remoted into serially and couldn't get it to connect to the internet for various reasons. I installed 32-bit ubuntu 12.04 and tried to install some deb's and packages via the /media/usbdrive with little success. So now I just got my 2nd linux box which is a 64-bit duo-core Dell which I could run the GUI, connect to the internet and download some cool stuff. Now I have the 64-bit machine with 32-bit ubuntu 12.04 installed and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to copy everything from the 64-bit machine to the 32-bit machine using only the remote terminal serial to issue commands and the usb drive to transfer files.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options for installing packages without an internet connection:

1. **Using Keryx**

   [**Keryx**](https://launchpad.net/keryx) is a portable, cross-platform package manager that provides a graphical interface for gathering updates, packages, and dependencies for offline computers.
2. **Using the Synaptic package download script**

   Synaptic package manager has built-in feature to generate a [**package download script**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/PackageDownloadScript).
3. **Using apt-offline**

   [**apt-offline**](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/apt-offline/) is an offline text based apt package manager.
4. **Installing downloaded packages**

   - [**.deb packages**](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/147044) (here fits the part from the question relating to the [installation of Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/q/79280/147044))
   - [**.tar.gz and .tar.bz2 packages**](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/147044)
   - [**.rpm packages**](https://askubuntu.com/q/2988/147044)

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: I couldn't find where to download Keryx - several sites gave a server error and 1 said there was no version for 12.04 (precise) - I found Synaptic 0.75.9 and extracted it to a directory and ran autoconf to create the configure script from configure.in and then ran the ./configure and got errors: ./configure: line 2270: syntax error near unexpected token `synaptic,'
./configure: line 2270: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(synaptic, 0.75.9)'
I'm new to Ubuntu - maybe this is an easy fix?

Comment: @DanH For Keryx try [this link](https://launchpad.net/keryx/stable/1.0-release/+download/keryx_1.0-public21.tar.gz) for .tar.gz file or [this link](https://launchpad.net/keryx/stable/1.0-release/+download/keryx_1.0-public21_all.deb) for .deb file.

Comment: @DanH Synaptic can be found in [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/) or you can take it from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/synaptic/0.80~exp2raring1/+files/synaptic_0.80~exp2raring1.tar.gz). Check out [the dependincies (packages relationships)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/synaptic)