# BSD compatible commands

Tags: command-line, bsd

The BSD versions of a number of basic Unix commands, such as `ls`,  behave differently from the GNU versions used by Ubuntu.

Some operating systems, including Solaris, provide BSD commands in addition to the "native" ones.  For example, Solaris 9 has a `/usr/ucb` directory in addition to the `/usr/bin` directory, with some commands names duplicated.

Is there something similar for Ubuntu? I haven't found a relevant package, either one that's installable via `apt` or as source.

Answer (score 5):

Reading through [this Unix and Linux post titled "Any options to replace GNU coreutils on Linux?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6182/70524), one option could be [the Heirloom project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html) toolset. It includes [`ls`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/ls.1.html), among other things, and hopefully that `ls` behaves like you want it to. Of interest is this point in the highlights:

> Multiple versions of many utilities are provided to approach
>   **compatibility with various specifications** and Unix flavors, namely
>   SVID3/SVR4, SVID4/SVR4.2MP, POSIX.2-1992/SUSV2, POSIX.1-2001/SUSV3,
>   and 4BSD (SVR4 /usr/ucb).

Note the last item: "4BSD (SVR /usr/ucb)".

It doesn't have an Ubuntu package that I know of. The [installation instructions](http://heirloom.cvs.sourceforge.net/heirloom/heirloom/README?view=markup) build an RPM, which you could convert using `alien` and then install. [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2988/158442)

Comment: Looks promising. I haven't had a chance to try it yet.