# RPM on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, rpm

I was checking out the packages I had installed on my system, and I noticed that I had rpm (I don't remember installing it. I think it got installed along with some other package). Can I use it to install rpm packages on my system (Ubuntu GNOME 17.04)? Or will it not work?

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/rpm.8.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto

Comment: Also: [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2988/158442)