# Ubuntu saying failed dependencies even after installing — how can I fix?

Tags: apt, aws, fuse

I am currently trying to install the following github rpm on my Ubuntu 20 server on AWS.

https://github.com/usrecnik/ddlfs

Currently when I try to install I get an error:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://github.com/usrecnik/ddlfs/releases/download/2.3/ddlfs-2.3.rpm
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
Retrieving https://github.com/usrecnik/ddlfs/releases/download/2.3/ddlfs-2.3.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        fuse is needed by ddlfs-2.3-1.x86_64
        fuse-libs is needed by ddlfs-2.3-1.x86_64
        libaio is needed by ddlfs-2.3-1.x86_64
```

But when I go to install fuse as an example -- sudo apt-get install -y fuse

It says it is already installed.

How can this be? I have never used a ubuntu server in my life and truly only need it to run this very specific github project. So I am a complete novice. Any advice would make my day. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- he has listed a .deb file, is that what I should be trying?

Comment: Thank you! that worked

Comment: Great! I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

RPM (`.rpm`) packages are made for Red Hat, CentOS and other distributions that use Red Hat Package Manager (RPM).

You should use a DEB (`.deb`) package if available.  DEB packages are made for `dpkg` and `apt` which correspond to the package management system used by Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu.

If you really want to install the RPM (*not recommeded*), please read [How do I install and manage RPMs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2988/how-do-i-install-and-manage-rpms)